# How to exclude specific files from caching

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm using `config-overrides.js` with `string-replace-loader` in order to change the content of a file **before** being compiled by webpack.

But because of the caching system of webpack ([cache option](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache/#cache)) the loader is not being executed, if I set `cache = false` everything works just fine (exactly like the production build).

I've spent several hours trying to understand how to **exclude** a file from caching, but whatever I've found does not work as expected and I'm kinda out of ideas.

Is there any way to achieve this **without completely disabling the caching system**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[EDIT]**
I know the question asks about **files**, but my problem was related to the `index.js` file which imports a component conditionally based on a specific value inside an external config file.

After some more couple of hours of investigating I've found what I was looking for.

[Here](https://github.com/webpack/changelog-v5/blob/master/guides/persistent-caching.md#version) is the official documentation regarding this exactly use case.

Basically what we can do to invalidate the cache is to use the `cache` object as below:

```
cache = {
      type: 'filesystem',
      version: `${any external variable/value which may change in the future}`, // Keep the `${}`
};
```

**`cache.version` is a string. Passing a different string will invalidate the persistent cache.**

I'm using it like this and it's working great so far.

```js
const invalidateCacheValues = [
  config.my_value_0,
  config.my_value_1
];

webpackConfig['cache'] = {
  type: 'filesystem',
  version: `${invalidateCacheValues.join('|')}`,
};
```